# Cross Browser Compatible HTML

Tags: cross-browser

Is there any tool available which will check my html page for different browsers and also suggest the changes I should make to make them cross browser compatible?

Some of my html pages are not working fine with IE and some in Chrome.

Comment: IME, Firefox is the most standards compliant browser - while there are some bits of functionality that other browsers fail to handle rather providing a superset of functionality, using Firefox as a reference platform saved me a lot of pain compared with MSIE

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like http://browsershots.org/ to see how it looks in all kind of browsers. But it stop there, it will not give you any solutions for the problems.
You just don't need to install all kind of browsers on all kind of operating systems.